# Python function in subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to run a bash command that takes as input the argument of a python function, like this example:

```
def myfunc(r1, r2):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.run(['r1 + r2'])
```

I actually have a more complicated bash code that anyway should take as input the arguments of the function, so I think this example explain this. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*? Did you try the code? Did something happen that was different from what you wanted? Do you understand why it did that?

Answer (score 1):

i usualy use this function:

```
import os
def python_to_bash(cli_args):
    output = os.popen(cli_args).read()
    return output

return = python_to_bash([r1,r2])
print(return)
```